# $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is increasing. $\{y\in\mathbb{R}:\#f^{-1}(\{y\})\geq 2\}$ can contain at most countably many points. Why?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 24 on p.40 in Exercises 2B in this book.

> Exercise 24
> Suppose $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set and $f:B\to\mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function. Prove that $f(B)$ is a Borel set.

I found [an answer to Exercise 24 by Sangchul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4214625/384082).

Let $D:=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:\#f^{-1}(\{y\})\geq 2\}.$
Sangchul Lee wrote as follows:

> $D$ can contain at most countably many points.

Why?

Is the following proposition true?

> If $S$ is a set of disjoint nondegenerate intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, then $S$ is at most countable.

Comment: In each interval fix a rational number. These numbers for disjoint intervals are different. Hence there can be at most countably mamy intervals.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you very much for your answer.